# Dialog send - multiple friends

Tags: facebook, dialog, send

Can you explain.
An example from the other site - it adds 2 users to the sending.

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=116412671734664&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&redirect_uri=http://www.jetsetter.com/&to=100000910418225,590528674

Our link - adds only the first one.

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=136365146450254&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&redirect_uri=http://belvg.info/cutandblow/&to=100000910418225,590528674

an you explain the reason of this?
Maybe you have some guidlines of where should we search for the reason and how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Is your app in sandbox mode?

Comment: Doesn't matter if the app is in sandbox mode or not.

Comment: FB's docs read "to: A user ID or username to which to send the message. Once the dialog comes up, the user can specify additional users..." ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/ ) and my experience has always been a limit of one person. 

I'm not sure why the rule doesn't seem to apply to jetsetter.com though.

Comment: Yes, that's the question. If they can do it maybe we somehow can as well. We can live without it but it will provide users better usability.

Comment: Here's the test URL where it doesn't work: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=109456635348&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&redirect_uri=http://www.stay.com/&to=100000910418225,590528674

Answer (score 1):

It's being worked on as a bug.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/314701778595814?