# Failed to populate Facebook send dialog with more than 1 recipient using Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook

I've struggled with this issue for the past 3 hrs and googled/SO a ton of links.

Sample code:

```
<script>
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    picture: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/i/fb3.png',
    name: 'XX',
    description: 'Blah blah blah',
    link: 'http://www.google.com',
    to: [123, 456]  // fake ids
}, function(r) {});
</script>
```

Trying the above in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ works like a charm, the dialog is pre-populated with 2 users. However, it does not work on my site (local or test environment), only 1 user is ever added.

Many other sites can prepopulate multiple users just fine (e.g. jetsetter), and from this link (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6469748/facebook-send-dialog-to-multiple-friends-using-a-recipients-arrays), it seems that it is supported in JS SDK, though the url method may not work.

[Dialog send - multiple friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205562/dialog-send-multiple-friends)
Another user seems to have similar issue.

Does anyone know of, or can suggest, possible reasons or directions for further investigation?  The only thing I can think of is possible conflict b/w our JS and the FB JS SDk, but that is so very unlikely...

This issue repros in both FF/Chrome for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let me just put this out there so others won't shoot themselves...

turns out you need to be "whitelisted" to be able to add multiple users and send messages to them. This is undocumented "special treatment".

Comment: @BadalSingh Xerion: Did you find the way. Plz share

Comment: Didn't bother to get that. You need to talk to FB directly. and your company needs to be big enough for them to care, I would presume.